# How to trace the edges on matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab, edge-detection

I am doing my Bachelor's project on Road extraction. I have detected the line segments(edges) in the image using hough transform. I need to detect the curved lines in the road and link them(edge linking).[image: Kindly] help me with matlab coding.

Comment: have you tried sobel edge detector with some morphological operations such as dilation?

Comment: I have tried canny edge detector and hough transform so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible pre-processing apporach is to use `imdilate(I,strel('disk',5))` to thicken the road lines a little bit.

If you are trying `houghlines`, probably one parameter that you need to tune is the 'FillGap' which will connect the very short segments (you can try to change this parameter yourself to observe the effect, along with the `MinLength` value):

```
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',30,'MinLength',15);
```

However, the road curves are not straight lines, so I won't recommend you to use hough transform. You may try `bwmorph(bw,'skel',N);` after you thicken the binarized road image. `N` is the iteration number that you need to tune.